# Dynamic configuration form

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, configuration

i need to do a configuration file wich allow an admin to select a lot of terms from a vocabulary. Then i want to make a form with 2 select field : Vocabulary and Terms. So, i can select the vocabulary i want and a lot of terms of a vocabulary but i don't know to show all terms of the selected vocabulary.

My code :

```
/*
 * ==================================
 * CONFIGURATION MODULE
 * ==================================
 */
function food_truck_form_admin() {
  $form = array();
  $form['vocabulary'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Vocabulary',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => food_truck_form_vocabularies()
  );
  $form['terms'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Terms',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#options' => food_truck_form_terms('marqueurs')
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function food_truck_form_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/settings/food_truck_form'] = array(
      'title' => 'Food-Truck Configuration',
      'description' => 'Global configurations',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array(
          'food_truck_form_admin'
      ),
      'access arguments' => array(
          'administer food_truck_form settings'
      ),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

  return $items;
}

/*
 * ==================================
 * OTHER FUNCTIONS
 * ==================================
 */

/*
 * Return a term list of a vocabulary by it's machine name or null
 */
function food_truck_form_terms($machine_name) {
  if (! empty($machine_name)) {
    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name)->vid;
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
    foreach ($terms as $data) {
      $output[$data->tid] = $data->name;
    }
    return $output;
  }
  return NULL;
}
/*
 * Retur a vocabulary list or null
 */
function food_truck_form_vocabularies() {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  if (count((array) $vocabulary) != 0) {
    foreach ($vocabulary as $data) {
      $output[$data->vid] = $data->name;
    }
    return $output;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe i need to use a javascript script, but i don't know how to call my module method by an ajax request ^^

Comment: Drupal as an Ajax framework for forms for things like this. https://www.drupal.org/node/752056

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i've did this and this work perfectly :

```
/*
 * ==================================
 * CONFIGURATION MODULE
 * ==================================
 */
/**
 * Implementation of hook_admin()
 */
function food_truck_form_admin() {
  $form = array();
  $form['vocabulary'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Vocabulaires',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => food_truck_form_vocabularies(),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'terms_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'terms-wrapper',
          'event' => 'change'
      )
  );
  $form['terms'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Types de marqueurs',
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="terms-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#options' => food_truck_form_terms('marqueurs')
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function food_truck_form_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/settings/food_truck_form'] = array(
      'title' => 'Food-Truck Configuration',
      'description' => 'Global configurations',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array(
          'food_truck_form_admin'
      ),
      'access arguments' => array(
          'administer food_truck_form settings'
      ),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * CALLBACKS
 */
function terms_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $machine_name = $form['vocabulary']['#options'][$form_state['values']['vocabulary']];
  $form['terms']['#options'] = food_truck_form_terms($machine_name);
  return $form['terms'];
}
/*
 * ==================================
 * OTHER FUNCTIONS
 * ==================================
 */

/*
 * Return a term list of a vocabulary by it's machine name or null
 */
function food_truck_form_terms($machine_name) {
  if (! empty($machine_name)) {
    $vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($machine_name)->vid;
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tffree($vid);
    foreach ($terms as $data) {
      $output[$data->tid] = $data->name;
    }
    return $output;
  }
  return NULL;
}
/*
 * Retur a vocabulary list or null
 */
function food_truck_form_vocabularies() {
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  if (count((array) $vocabulary) != 0) {
    foreach ($vocabulary as $data) {
      $output[$data->vid] = $data->machine_name;
    }
    return $output;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```